# How to group DataFrame values by hour?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

My source CSV has time column e.g.

```
Time Attempt
12.07.2018 00:00:00  50
12.07.2018 00:15:00  60
...
13.07.2018 00:00:00  100
13.07.2018 00:15:00  30
```

I would like to group by dd/mm/yyyy HH24. In SQL, we can use `to_date('Time','dd/mm/yyyy hh24')` but in Spark I have tried but it shows errors below.
Please advise. Thank you very much.

```
    val dfAgg = df.select(
unix_timestamp($"time", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp")
,unix_timestamp($"time", "yyyy/MM/dd HH").cast(TimestampType).as("time2")
,to_date($"time","HH").as("time3")
,to_date($"time","yyyy/MM/dd").as("time4")
)
<console>:94: error: too many arguments for method to_date: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
   ,to_date($"time","HH").as("time3")
           ^
<console>:95: error: too many arguments for method to_date: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
   ,to_date($"time","yyyy/MM/dd").as("time4")
```

Comment: I guess that is a typo in the title,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.withColumn(“hour”,split(col(“Time”),” “) (1).substr(0,2))
  .groupBy(“Time”,”hour”)
  .sum(“Attempt”)
  .drop(“hour”)
  .withColumn(“Time”,split(col(“Time”),”:”)(0))
  .show
```

Comment: it can group by hour, but in the show we have both timestamp with full timestamp and hour. Can we have one timestamp in dd/mm/yyyy hh?

Answer (score 0):

Function "to_timestamp" can be used for convert string to timestamp:

```
  val data = List(
  ("12.07.2018 00:00:00", 50),
  ("12.07.2018 00:15:00", 60),
  ("13.07.2018 00:00:00", 100),
  ("13.07.2018 00:15:00", 30))

val df = data.toDF("time", "value").select(
  to_timestamp($"time", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
)
df.printSchema()
df.show(false)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- to_timestamp(`time`, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'): timestamp (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------------------+
|to_timestamp(`time`, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')|
+-------------------------------------------+
|2018-07-12 00:00:00                        |
|2018-07-12 00:15:00                        |
|2018-07-13 00:00:00                        |
|2018-07-13 00:15:00                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you Spark version is below 2.2.0

Spark 2.2.0 introduces `def to_date(e: Column, fmt: String)`. Check an API [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_date(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

You can you `to_timestamp()` function to create an hour windows:

```
  val df = data.toDF("time", "value")
    .select('time, 'value, to_timestamp('time, "dd.MM.yyyy HH") as "hour_window")
    .groupBy('hour_window).sum("value").show
```

returns:

```
+-------------------+----------+
|        hour_window|sum(value)|
+-------------------+----------+
|2018-07-13 00:00:00|       130|
|2018-07-12 00:00:00|       110|
+-------------------+----------+
```